# How to fix pyodbc dependency errors when upgrade Django from 2.1 to 2.2.13?

Tags: python, django, django-pyodbc, django-pyodbc-azure, django-mssql-backend

Since version 2.1 has been marked as insecure I need to upgrade at least to >=2.2. Github security suggests installing 2.2.13. I also need to install other packages that only work with Django >=2.2.

The Django upgrade is successful but when pipenv tries to lock the dependencies I get this error:

```
Warning: Your dependencies could not be resolved. You likely have a mismatch in your sub-dependencies.
```

I googled this and the only way I stop getting this error is by placing these two dependencies under [dev-packages]:

```
django-pyodbc-azure = "<2.1"
django-pyodbc = "<2.1"
```

But when I try to run the server I get this:

```
ImproperlyConfigured("Django %d.%d.%d is not supported." % VERSION[:3])
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Django 2.2.13 is not supported.
```

I also googled this and the solution that shows up is to manually change the conditions for raising this error. I do that and then I get this other error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'sql_server.pyodbc' isn't an available database backend.
Try using 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
    'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql', 'sqlite3'
```

I googled this too but the solutions that worked for other people didn't work for me. I've been stuck at this point for days. Please send help!

Other info:
I am using these two params:

```
ENGINE':'sql_server.pyodbc'
'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server'
```

**Note:** If you know another way I can use these packages with a newer version of Django please share it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`django-pyodbc-azure` is no longer maintained, unfortunately. There's a new package you can use which works as a drop-in replacement. It supports Django 2.2 and 3.0.

https://pypi.org/project/django-mssql-backend/

I'd recommend that you entirely remove all references to `pyodbc`, `django-pyodbc`, and `django-pyodbc-azure`. Then update your dependencies (for example, in a `Pipfile` or `requirements.txt`) to add:

```
django-mssql-backend==2.8.1
django>=2.2,<3
```

Give that a try in a new virtual environment when you get a chance to ensure you don't have `django-pyodbc-azure` hanging around. If you have any further problems we can work through them in comments and amend the answer. I don't think you'll need it, but I have a more in depth guide available here: https://www.pyphilly.org/django-and-sql-server-2020-edition/

Comment: I know this is old, but I just followed these instructions and am still getting the error. Any guidance?

Comment: @AlliDeacon Can you start a new question and include what versions of: Django, django-mssql-backend, pyodbc, as well as what underlying driver you're using (FreeTDS, MSODBC), and what OS (CentOS, Ubuntu, Windows, Mac)? Then link the question here. I'm happy to take a look.